# DataFrame merge to exclude extra index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframe df1 and df2 and use the script below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
 'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})

df = df1.join(df2.iloc[1:].reset_index(), how='inner')
```

But there is one more column named 'index' which I don't want. Is there anyway to remove it?

```
    A   B  index   C   D
0  A0  B0      1  C1  D1
1  A1  B1      2  C2  D2
2  A2  B2      3  C3  D3
```

What I want is just like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C1  D1
1  A1  B1  C2  D2
2  A2  B2  C3  D3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `drop=True` within your code.

```
df = df1.join(df2.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True), how='inner')

    A   B   C   D
0   A0  B0  C1  D1
1   A1  B1  C2  D2
2   A2  B2  C3  D3
```